# ionic angular bluetooth discover devices

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I have issue with discover sex toy device. I tried to use "Bluetooth-serial","BLE","BluetoothLE", none of the bluetooth found anything. I checked it in forest where there is not single device. I guess that sex toy is hidden and need something options for bluetooth [image of sex toy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjVNd.jpg)

I know that sex toy connect by ServiceUUID, but i can't recognize ServiceUUID without no device discover. Who did it using ionic angular bluetooth? I need some advices

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Search for the device by using a BLE scanner app like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) first. That way you can ensure that it is not a problem with your own implementation.

Comment: I used it and there aren't any devices around but this sex toy is can connect to app which used Bluetooth. My goal is connecting to device using ionic cordova
True app is wriited on Android Studio or Java